# Laravel Resource controller for filtering

Tags: laravel

I have a `resource` Controller for an API that I'm developing for displaying records that can be filtered by `Type` and `Customer` and I have the following methods that can get this data:

`index`

`show` -> requires an `parameter (id)`

Can I therefore put a `request` inside the `index` method for filtering all of the entries back or is it bad practise for doing this? My code looks like the following:

```
  public function index()
    {
          $entries = \App\Ent::where(function($en) {
              $request = app()->make('request');

              if($request->has('type')) {
                  $en->where('type', '=', $request->get('type'));
              }

              if($request->has('customer')) {
                  $en->where('customer', '=', $request->get('customer'));
              }

          })->get();

          dd($entries);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filtering in Laravel is very simple and you don't need to do this. In your `Ent` model, define the following:

```
public function scopeFilter($query, $filters)
  {
    if( isset($filters['type']) ){
      $query->where('type', '=', $filters['type']);
    }
   // keep going for all of your filters
  }
```

And on your Controller index method you can:

```
public function index()
{
  $entries = \App\Ent::filter(['type', 'customer'])->get();
  dd($entries);
}
```

**EDIT**

To help you make more sense of this, let's filter `Ent` on the `type` column in the database.

Route:

```
Route::get('/ent', 'EntController@index');
```

Ent Model:

```
class Ent extends Model
{
  public function scopeFilter($query, $filters)
  {
    if( isset($filters['type']) ){
      $query->where('type', '=', $filters['type']);
    }
  }
}
```

Ent Controller:

```
class EntController extends Controller {
  index()
  {
    $entries = \App\Ent::filter(['type'])->get();
    return view('ent.index', compact('entries'));
   }
}
```

Let's say for the sake of this example we are just going to put a form on the same blade template we are outputting our list:

```
@foreach( $entries as $entry )
 <p>{{ $entry->type }}</p>
@endforeach

<form method="GET" action="/ent">

 {{ csrf_field() }}

 <input type="text" name="type" />

 <input type="submit" value="Filter" />

</form>
```

So now, if I were to go into that form and type 'Foo Bar' and hit submit, you would get what would look something like this in SQL

`SELECT * FROM Ent WHERE type='foo bar'`

Or in other words, all `Ent` with the `type` column `=` 'foo bar'.

When I give a user the ability to type raw text in to filter, I like to give them the benefit of the doubt and use `LIKE` instead of `=`. So for example we would just change our scopeFilter method:

```
if( isset($filters['type']) ){
  $query->where('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['type'] . '%');
}
```

Another thing to note here, the `filters[name]` is the name of the `<input>` field, NOT the name of the column in your database. You target the column in the `$query` extension, NOT in the `$filters` array. See below example:

```
if( isset($filters["ent_type"] ){
 $query->where('type', '=', $filters["ent_type"]);
}
```

On my form that would be

```
<input name="ent_type" type="text" />
```

Comment: Great thanks. Are `type`, `customer` variables and not actual names of the things that are being filtered? As these will be passed through URL.. like `?type=Car&` Currently outputting `dd($filters['type']` will just show `type` where I want the actual value

Comment: Yes, the `$filter[name]` if the name of the `GET` or `POST` variable. Then in the acutal query modifier, you target your DB column.

Comment: It's not making sense though.. `$request->get('type'); // = "Testing"` so therefore: `::filter([$request->get('type'), 'customer'])->get();` the value would be `Testing` which means inside the model, the if statement will never get triggered ?

Comment: Don't use `$request->get('type')` inside your filter just use the code I have, `filter(['type', 'customer'])`. Laravel magic will already assume that everything passed to that array in filter is a POST or GET variable.

Comment: I have.. `dd($filters);` inside the `scopeFilter` method and accessing `mysite.com/foo?type=car` which just gives me an array of two values `type` & `customer` ?

Comment: And whats wrong with that? Of corse you have that because you asked for those filters in your `index()` method. I'll edit my answer to try and help you make more sense of this.

Comment: thanks please do. I'm just confused because it doesn't look like laravel is taking the values for what's passed through to the scope, only the array values. For example, in my question I do this: '$type = $request-get('type')' but in your example the if statement is never reached

Comment: thanks for this I'll take a look when I'm next at my machine. I notice on your update, your doing it through a form. Does the same apply if I'm passing the filters through a URL parameter? Could this be where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You can pass them trough as a URL param for sure! So:

`<a href="/ent?type=foo_bar">Filter On Foo Bar</a>`

Comment: I had to modify the Controller Index method from Ent::filter(['type', 'customer']) to Ent::filter($request->all()) for this to work. @Phorce comment on Jul 12 19:29 is correct that only the $_GET names are passed in, not the values.